# Sailsjs not outputting bigint

Tags: mysql, sails.js

I'm trying to display a table in sails from a mysql table using the mysql-adapter
The ID's in the table are in the following format

```
14482773051001000000
14482773051001000001
14482773051001000002
```

But sails is spitting out every ID like

```
14482773051001000000
14482773051001000000
14482773051001000000
```

Basically replacing all the last digits with 0.

I've tried autoPK false and setting size to 64 for a bigint, but to no avail.

My attributes are currently set like so:

```
 autoPK: false,
 schema: true,

  attributes: {
    id: {
  type: 'integer',
      size: 64,
      unique: true,
      autoIncrement:true,
      primaryKey: true
    },
```

Can anybody help? :/

---

## Answer

Answer was to turn on supportBigNumbers: true via the MysqlAdapter

myMysqlConnection: {
adapter: 'sails-mysql',
host: '192.168.x.x',
user: 'username',
password: 'password',
database: 'myDb',
supportBigNumbers: true
},

Thanks to @japel https://github.com/japel on gitter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer was to turn on supportBigNumbers: true via the MysqlAdapter

```
myMysqlConnection: {
  adapter: 'sails-mysql',
  host: '192.168.x.x',
  user: 'username',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'myDb',
  supportBigNumbers: true
},
```

Thanks to @japel https://github.com/japel on gitter